# Running a MySQL query using a string in php

Tags: php, mysql

**Answer found (syntax):** The column name of my string had to be encased in backticks " ` "  as they contained spaces. Note that this means that the majority of this post has no relevance to the issue. The code has been corrected in case someone wants to do something similar.

So, I am doing a foreach loop to assign a value (1/0) to non-static columns in my database (it needs to support addition/deletion/editing of columns). I am using $connectionvar->query($queryvar); to do my queries which worked fine up until now when I'm trying to use a custom built string as $queryvar in order to change the column name to a variable within the loop. I've been outputting this string through echo and it looks exactly like my functional queries but somehow doesn't run. I've attempted to use eval() to solve this but to no avail (I feel safe using eval() as the user input is radio buttons).

Here's the loop as well as my thought processes behind the code. If something seems incoherent or just plain stupid, refer to my username.

```
foreach($rdb as $x) {  //$rdb is a variable retrieved from $_POST earlier in the code.
$pieces = explode("qqqppp", $x); //Splits the string in two (column name and value) (this is a workaround to radio buttons only sending 1 value)
$qualname = $pieces[0];  //Column name from exploded string
$qualbool = $pieces[1];  //desired row value from exploded string
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET ';  //building the query string
$sql .= '`$qualname`';
$sql .= '=\'$qualbool\' WHERE username=\'$profilename\''; //$profilename is retrieved earlier to keep track of the profile I am editing.
eval("\$sql = \"$sql\";");  //This fills out the variables in the above string.
$conn->query($sql); //Runs the query (works)
echo ' '.$sql.' <br>'; //echoes the query strings on my page, they have the exact same output format as my regular queries have.
}
}}
```

Here's an example of what the echo of the string looks like:

> UPDATE users SET Example Qualification 3='1' WHERE username='Admin2'

For comparison, echoing a similar (working) query variable outside of this loop (for static columns) looks like this:

> UPDATE users SET profiletext='qqq' WHERE username='Admin2'

As you can see the string format is definitely as planned, yet somehow doesn't execute. What am I doing wrong?

PS. Yes I did research this to death before posting it, as I have hundreds of other issues since I started web developing a month ago. Somehow this one has left me stumped though, perhaps due to it being a god awful hack that nobody would even consider in the first place.

Comment: For future reference, you will get a better answer faster if you also include the error output you are getting.

Comment: Alright, noted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks when referring to column names which have spaces in them.  So your first query from the loop is outputting as this:

```
UPDATE users SET Example Qualification 3='1' WHERE username='Admin2'
```

But it should be this:

```
UPDATE users SET `Example Qualification 3`='1' WHERE username='Admin2'
```

Change your PHP code to this:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET `';  // I added an opening backtick around the column name
$sql .= '$qualname`';         // I added a closing backtick around the column name
$sql .= '=\'$qualbool\' WHERE username=\'$profilename\'';
```

Comment: Holy cow, this did the trick. Thank god it was just a minor syntax error. Thanks a lot. Guess I should figure out which of the 2 queries did the work now.

Comment: How is variable replaced with value in single quotes?

Comment: @ReneKorss Could you be a bit more specific? If you're wondering about stub 2 of the $sql string then it works because I run it through eval which reads it as code. I originally solved this by encasing the variables in  '. .' but I changed it to this to check if it was the source of the problem.

Comment: @noobequaltotrue Ofcourse. Missed that part of code. :) All clear.

Answer (score 0):

`Example Qualification 3` : Is that the name of your Mysql Column name ?

You shouldnt use spaces nor upper / lower case in your columnname.

Prefere : `example_qualification_3`

EDIT :

To get column name and Comment

`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM users`

Comment: The columns are defined/edited/added/deleted by the administrators of the site to account for the changes in possible types of qualifications. I usually stick to the proper format, but I can't think of a way to do it within this design. Originally I had qualifications in a separate table but hooking them together was a hassle. If you have a legitimate reason for me to overhaul this decision, I will do it (other than minor syntax issues like this one).

Comment: You do what you can, its ok. Im just sad to see unqualified administrators naming their databases so badly. For sure, if the whole database is like that and your project to advanced, you are not going to change this. But if you are only at the beginning, I would recommend to change.

Comment: Ah to be honest it's my own hacky design. I use the column names as display values as well, which is why the naming has to support messes like this. The columns represent qualifications that users may or may not have to take on certain job tasks like "Row boat instructor". As these requirements vary I need to give them the opportunity to add these as they go using the website. Maybe it's a total hackjob solution to use the column name to get a second value from a field, but the scope is low enough for it to suffice.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to name your column `example_qualification_3` and to comment it as `Example Qualification 3`. Then use the requests I just add in my answer to retrieve your column name + its comment (User friendly name).  (I suppose you are working on MySQL)

Comment: That sounds like a reasonably painless way to get this done. Thanks.